# I am unable to extract numeric fields from a PostgreSQL database using Dart and the Postgres package

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple, single row, PostgreSQL database table that includes a numeric(8,2) field, set to 120.00, and a character field set to 'N'.
This is a Windows 10 setup.
When I run the following Dart program the result is unexpected:

```
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

void main() async {
  print('Attaching to DB...');
  final conn = PostgreSQLConnection(
    'localhost',
    5432,
    'pdpdb',
    username: 'XXXXXXX',
    password: 'XXXXXXX',
  );

  await conn.open();
  print('Connected to DB');

  var results = await conn.query('''
    SELECT verification, balance FROM contacts 
  ''');

  print(results);

  await conn.close();
}
```

My result is this:

```
Attaching to DB...
Connected to DB
[[N,  ╔     ╗ 2]]
```

So the 'N' is clear, but the numeric field is gibberish!
Why am I not seeing 120.00 as I do when I run the same command using pgAdmin's query tool:

[image]

I have tried to parse the field as if it were a double, but that gives me:

```
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Invalid double
```

I am sure this must be something obvious so any hints will be gratefully received.  Thank you.

If I write a similar process using toMaps():

```
final results = await conn.query('''
      SELECT verification, balance FROM contacts
      ''').toMaps();

  print(results);
```

I get the output:

```
[{verification: N, balance:
```

Suggesting that something has broken the output.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer - more of a work around:

It seems that the Postgres package doesn't support NUMERIC fields as Dart doesn't have an equivalent type.
This workaround: 
[github issue](https://github.com/stablekernel/postgresql-dart/issues/108)
suggests the use of CASTing the numeric field to a float within the SELECT statement.
I've tried it and it does work.  Granted it is not ideal, but as it works that helps me out a lot at the moment.